# How to make a multidimensional array from one dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am preparing data for a convolutional neural network model. I am new to deep learning and want to start with seeing how LeNet 5 will work with my data (as it has few parameters).

I prepared 9 NumPy arrays, every array has dimension (10530, 32, 32, 1), 10530 images and each image is 32 x 32 pixel. I want to make one array has (10530, 32, 32, 9)

I tried np.concatenate but it is not working. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: You have to specfiy the correct axis (in this case the last one). `np.concatenate([a, b, c, ...], axis=-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.concatenate` is the way:

```
np.concatenate(list_of_arrays, axis=-1)
```